# Swagger throwing "Not a valid parameter definition"

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I am creating API documentation utilizing Swagger UI.  I have many errors that say "Not a valid parameter definition" and I don't know why.  Can anyone tell what or why this is happening?  I include a section of the code and a picture with the line numbers and the error descriptions.

swagger example

```
#sys_application

/api/application/add:
  post:
    description: Adds specified application(s).
    parameters:

    - name: name
      in: body
      description: name of the application
      required: true
      type: string

    - name: appId
      in: body
      description: application id
      required: true
      type: string

    - name: icon
      in: body
      description: application icon
      required: true
      type: string

    - name: state
      in: body
      description: current state of the application
      required: true
      type: string

    - name: profileRoute
      in: body
      description: embedded profile route that is displayed within the map app
      required: true
      type: string

    - name: type
      in: body
      description: type of the application
      required: true
      type: string

    - name: permissions
      in: body
      description: user permissions for application
      required: false
      type: string

    - name: subscriptions
      in: body
      description: application subscriptions
      required: false
      type: string
```

swagger error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use `in: body`, the spec expects a `schema` element, such as:

```
name: user
in: body
schema:
  type: object
  properties:
    userId:
      type: string
```

If you're *not* using a body parameter, you are expected to use a primitive value, such as `type: string`.